# URL variable getting lost when using upload button on a managed file

Tags: forms, files

I have a D7 form that I made using the form API. The URL to the form contains a URL variable like so `www.mysite.com/myform?id=123456`. (I know it would be better to do `www.mysite.com/myform/123456`, but that is another issue and I can't do that right now for an unrelated reason).

Anyway, I am first checking for the existence of that `id` variable in the URL and if it exists, I am putting it into a hidden form field so that it gets submitted with the form. This works great until someone uses the managed file form element that I have for someone to upload a file with. If they choose their file and then click the submit button at the bottom of the form, the id exists in the hidden field just fine and gets submitted and is available in the form submit function. However, if the user chooses their file and clicks the `upload` button next to the managed file form element and THEN clicks the submit button, the id is lost. I'm assuming it's because the upload button is doing an AJAX submit and then rebuilding the form except when it's getting rebuilt, that URL variable for ID no longer exists in the URL that's being used, so the hidden form field does not get set again.

Is there a better way to go about this?

THANKS

Here is the code I am using:

```
function apex_onboard_form($form_state) {

  $form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");

  if (isset($_GET['orderId'])) {
    $form['orderId'] = array(
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#default_value' => $_GET['orderId'],
    );    
  }  

  $form['resume_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'Resume Upload',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#upload_location' => "public://resume_tmp/",
    '#upload_validators'=>  array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array(variable_get('resume_allowed_extensions', 'doc docx pdf txt rtf')),
      'file_validate_size' => array(variable_get('resume_max_upload_size', '2') * 1024 * 1024),
    ),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  ); 

  return $form;
}
```

If the user clicks the "Upload" button next to the file field and then clicks submit, the orderId field does not get passed to the submit function. If the user chooses a file and then clicks submit without clicking upload first, the orderId comes across fine.

Comment: as a last resort, you could employ some JS to fill the field on submit (field would be assuredly filled before being sent to server) - but it would fail if JS was turned off

Comment: It would be helpful if we had some of the code to look at, that way we can see what may be happening to the variable or offer a solution.

Comment: Post your code.